# web development - deletion of user data?

Tags: web, filesystems

I have finished my first complex web application and I have found out it is probably better to use "isDeleted" flags in db than hard-deleting records. But I wonder what is the recommended approach for data that are stored on filesystem (e.g. photos). Should I delete them when their related entity is (soft-)deleted or keep them as they are? Can junk accumulation cause running out of storage in practice?

Comment: Storage is pretty cheap.  You'd have to accumulate a _lot_ of data to run out.

Comment: Consider the question of "would your users want their personal data collected somewhere even after deleting their accounts?"

Comment: It depends on how useful is going to be. Only you can judge the trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely can - you'll need to gather some stats on how much data the typical account generates, and then figure out how many deletions you're seeing to sort out how much junk data will pile up and/or when you'll fill up your storage.

You might also want to try using something like [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store your data - at that point, the only reason you would need to delete things would be because it was costing you too much to store it.